# Как сделать сортировку выборки в Laravel по значению в таблице?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Есть таблица:

```
| id | name    | role  |
|----|---------|-------|
| 1  | John    | admin |
| 2  | Tom     | user  |
| 3  | Paul    | user  |
| 4  | Mikle   | moder |
| 5  | Lindsey | admin |
```

Как отсортировать так, что бы значения поля `role` были в таком порядке при выводе:
1. admin
2. moder
3. user

То есть коллекция пользователей должна выглядеть так если смотреть по id: `[1, 5, 4, 2, 3]`

Comment: `ORDER BY role ASC, id`.

Answer (score 2):

Тут может быть несколько решений в зависимости от условий.

1. Самый простой показал [@Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437) в комментарии. Но здесь условие, что твои роли всегда в таком же алфавитном порядке:

```
// отсортирует по роли в алфавитном порядке. При одинаковой роли будет отсортировано по id
App\User::orderBy('role')->get();
// сортировка по роли, потом по имени
App\User::orderBy('role')->orderBy('name')->get();
```

2. Для кастомной сортировки в `mysql` (спецы по другим БД пусть пишут комментарии) есть оператор `CASE`. Его уже используешь, когда тебе надо сортировать по другому условию:

```
$sortRules = [
  'admin' => 1,
  'manager' => 2,
  'customer' => 3, // сбилась алфавитная сортировка тут
  'user' => 4,
];

// (CASE WHEN role = 'admin' THEN 1 WHEN role = 'manager' THEN 2 ... ELSE 9999) ASC
$rawOrderSql = '(CASE ' . collect($sortRules)->map(function($order, $role){
    return "WHEN role = '{$role}' THEN {$order}";
})->implode(' ') . ' ELSE 9999 END) ASC';

App\User::orderByRaw($rawOrderSql)->get();
```